# how to count the total number of sheets in an Excel file using talend

Tags: excel, etl, talend

I have one requirement in which I am doing some pre-run checks for my Talend jobs.

We are checking the file exist in the directory or not, and accordingly we are loading the pre-run table.
But one the excel file have multiple sheets, I need to need if the total no of sheet in the excel workbook is 2 or not, and accordingly make an entry in the pre-run table.

Right now I am using Tfile_list and using and if condition as below:-

**((Integer)globalMap.get("tFileList_11_NB_FILE"))==0**

To check the no of file. But unable to figure it out to check no of sheets in excel file.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use a component developed by the community to achieve this: tFileExcelSheetList.
It allows you to list the sheets of your excel file, and get the count.
You can get it from [here](https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplaceproductoverview:marketplace=marketplace%252F1&p=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F542&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F542%252Fitems%252F2939).

If you don't want to use a custom component, you can achieve it this way, but it involves reading all the data from the file:
[image]

Check "All sheets" on tFileInputExcel in order to read data from all sheets.
tMap is used to get the current sheet name from the global variable:
[image]

```
(String)globalMap.get("tFileInputExcel_1_CURRENT_SHEET")
```

tUniqRow gets only unique sheet names since you will be getting the same sheet name for every row from the same sheet.